# Visual Studio requires remove/add of a reference to a newly re-built dll

Tags: c++, assembly-references

**Background:**

I have two applications each in Visual Studio 2010 (separate solutions, directories, etc.).

Application A has two projects which produce .dlls that are both referenced by a project in Application B

**Problem:**

Whenever I rebuild Application A's solution, the dlls are rebuilt as well (obviously) and then in order to get the project from Application B to compile correctly, I'm forced to remove the assembly references to the Application A dlls and re-add them.

This is a problem when trying to use MSBuild to automate release builds for Application B.

**Question:**

Is there a reason why this step is required?  Is there a way to force Visual Studio to ignore the attributes of the outdated assembly reference and compile using the new dll? I assume that the root of the problem is in the "Public Key Token" or "Version" property of the assembly reference.

**EDIT:**

To be clear, Application B is a C++ application.  The question boils down to whether a workaround exists to allow a C++ assembly reference to behave like a C# assembly reference who's "Specific Version" property is set to FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

Despite the option not being present in the properties pane for the reference, by hand editing the vcxproj file you can still add the tag:

```
<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
```

to the references, which fixes this issue.